# Constant CPU Frequency at Base 1.1 GHz on Intel Pentium Silver N5000

Tags: performance, cpu

I'm experiencing an issue with my ASUS x507ma laptop, which is equipped with an Intel Pentium Silver N5000 (Gemini Lake) processor. On various Linux distributions such as Ubuntu, CentOS, or Debian, the CPU frequency is constantly fixed at the base frequency of 1.1 GHz. I monitored this using the command watch

```
cat /proc/cpuninfo | grep MHz
```

After trying different distributions, I installed Arch Linux and, to my surprise, everything worked out of the box. The CPU was properly recognized with dynamic frequency scaling based on the load. However, for my studies, I need to work on Ubuntu.

When I run

```
cpupower frequency-info
```

on Arch, the driver is identified as **intel_pstate**. In contrast, on Ubuntu, the same command indicates that the module is not found or the driver is not active for this CPU. I am including the output of `cpupower frequency-info` for both Arch and Ubuntu for reference.

Arch:

```
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 2.70 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 2.70 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 1.79 GHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS:

```
analyzing CPU 0:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: Not Available
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: Not Available
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
Not Available
  available cpufreq governors: Not Available
  Unable to determine current policy
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency:  Unable to call to kernel
  boost state support:
    Supported: no
    Active: no
```

Any insights on why this issue occurs on Ubuntu, but not on Arch Linux, and how I can resolve it for Ubuntu, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd have explored the details you provided for more clarity... eg. Arch is usually a much *newer* software stack; 20.04 is the 2020-April release of Ubuntu built prior to release, ie. much older... however 20.04 being a LTS release had kernel stack choice, and you didn't specify what kernel stack you opted to use?  Was it the original (GA) kernel stack of 20.04 thus very old; an OEM stack? or the latest HWE stack available for 20.04?  ie. 20.04 is a release, you didn't specify product (Server/Desktop which have different defaults) or clarify what kernel stack you opted to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same issue with my X507MA N5000 laptop. Here's how to fix it.

**Removing CPU Throttling Programs:**

Start by removing the **thermald** and **irqbalance** programs, as they can restrict CPU performance. You can do this using the following command:

```
sudo apt remove thermald irqbalance
```

**Installing the cpufreq GNOME Shell Extension:**

To improve CPU management, you'll need to install GNOME shell extension called **cpufreq**. But first you need to install the GNOME shell extensions system:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions
```

Next, add the Firefox browser extension for integrating GNOME shell extensions, which can be found at: [GNOME Shell integration for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/).

You can now install the cpufreq GNOME shell extension via Firefox from this link: [cpufreq GNOME extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1082/cpufreq/).

**Launching and Configuring the Extension:**

1. Access the "extensions" by pressing the Windows logo key on your keyboard.
   [image: executing the "extensions" app]
2. Ensure that the **cpufreq** extension is enabled.
   [image: (cpufreq extension is enabled)]
3. In the system tray, find and launch the **cpufreq** extension. There, you should:

- Enable the frequency boost
- Switch to the performance mode
- Check the
  option to "remember settings."

[image: (cpufreq screenshot)]

Hope this helps!